# Simple logic in C++. Not allowed to use an IF statement

Tags: c, if-statement, int, double

So I'm new to programming and learning C/C++. The assignment is to create a simple program that will compute the total of a given price and quantity of an item. The part that I am stumped on is that we are not allowed to use an "if or switch statement" in creating the program. We are required to ask the user if the item is taxable or not, using 1 as yes and 0 as no. Right now I have the program to calculate both and read out both taxed and non-taxed. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I know this is amateur and the most basic of programming.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAX_RATE 0.065
int main() {

  int item_quantity, taxable;
  float item_price, total_with_tax, total_without_tax, a, b;

  // Read in the price of the item

  printf("What is the price of the item? (Should be less than $100)\n");
  scanf("%f<100", &item_price);

  // Read in the quantity of the item being purchased

  printf("How many of the item are you purchasing? (Should be less than 100) \n");
  scanf("%d<100", &item_quantity);

  // Read in if it is taxable or not

  printf("Is the item a taxed item (1 = yes, 0 = no)?\n");
  scanf("%d", &taxable);

  // Calculate total with tax

  a = item_quantity*item_price*(1 + TAX_RATE);

  // Calculate total without tax

  b = item_quantity*item_price;

  printf("Your total purchase will cost $%.2f\n", a);

  printf("Your total purchase will cost $%.2f\n", b);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: You might try the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).  Since this is a homework assignment I'll leave the implementation with it t you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So `taxable` is either `0` or `1`. Now look at the similarity between these two lines:

```
a = item_quantity*item_price*(1 + TAX_RATE);
b = item_quantity*item_price;
```

How could you make these a single line that uses the value of `taxable` so that it does what the first line does when `taxable` is `1` and what the second line does when `taxable` is `0`? Which bit needs to change? How could you make that happen?

Since it's your assignment, I think that's enough of a clue.

---

You seem to be struggling. Okay, consider the following lines that do exactly the same as the above two lines:

```
a = item_quantity*item_price*(1 + TAX_RATE);
b = item_quantity*item_price*(1);
```

What's the difference between them? Something disappeared. What's an easy way to make something disappear using basic math operators?

The answer has nothing to do with anything special to C++. It's just math!

Comment: so after googling how to use a ternary operator I came up with the solution.

Comment: total = (taxable == 1) ? item_quantity*item_price*( 1 + TAX_RATE) : item_quantity*item_price;

Comment: @user3050104 The ternary operator is more complicated than you require. It's basically an `if` in disguise and I'm sure the person who gave you your assignment doesn't want you to use it. This is very easily solvable without an `if` or a ternary operator. You can do it using simple arithmetic.

Comment: Okay, but how could I recall those without an if statement though?

Comment: @user3050104 You don't need both equations. Just one single equation that adds the tax when the item is taxable and doesn't add the tax when it is not. When you figure it out, you will forever remember this technique - it is incredibly useful and so very simple.

Comment: @user3050104 Don't forget that `taxable` is an `int` with either value `0` or `1`. It can take part in the equation too!

Comment: I just don't get were it can differentiate when the user puts in a 0 or a 1

Comment: @user3050104 It doesn't need to differentiate. It just needs to add the tax in one case and not add it in the other. Further hint: you just need to add a single multiplication to the first line (and get rid of the second line). See if you can figure out what that multiplication is.

Comment: @user3050101 Maybe a better explanation: it differentiates based on the value of `taxable`. So if you use `taxable` in the equation in some way, you are differentiating between the two cases.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. Mutiply the tax rate by taxable

Comment: @user3050104 Boom! You got it. And now you can also show off your knowledge of ternary operators.

Answer (score 1):

The most common options for making decisions without an `if` or `switch` statement are the `&&` ("and" operator), `||` ("or" operator), `?:` (ternary operator), and `*` (multiplication operator).

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a way to negate the TAX_RATE if the user is giving you 0. It's a simple mathematical operation that we're trying to clue you in on.

Answer (score 0):

U can change the Equation:

a = item_quantity*item_price*(1 + TAX_RATE);

Add taxable variable in the equation in such a way that when taxable is 0,

Equation becomes:

a = item_quantity*item_price